# Fail in OR to + noun/gerund/infinitive?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

**TIL**: the phrase **["fail in + noun/gerund"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fail+in+(something))** means:

- *to not be successful in an attempt to do something.*

and the phrase **["fail to + infinitive"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fail)** means:

- *leave something undone*

According to the meanings above; thus:

> 1. The king **fails in** `the throne`.
>
>    > This means ***the king does something unsuccessfully in his reign.***
> 2. The king **fails to** `the throne`.
> 3. The king **fails to** `claim` the throne.
> 4. The king **fails in** `claiming` the throne.
>
>    > These mean the same as ***the king claims the throne unsuccessfully.***

**Do they have any other differences?**

`Thank you very much`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it is a cross post of the identical question on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471614/fail-in-or-to-noun-gerund-infinitive).

Comment: You've been asking essentially the same (if not exactly the same) question repeatedly both here and on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471614/fail-in-or-to-noun-gerund-infinitive) for days now. If you're not getting an answer you like, you shouldn't be posting the same question again in a different form or elsewhere. You should work on modifying the existing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your examples are not idiomatic.

In essence:

One fails **to** accomplish a task, assignment or similar

and

One fails **in** a project, ambition, aim, exam or similar

So the king would NOT fail **in the throne** but he might fail in his attempts to bring peace to his kingdom.

The king would NOT fail **to the throne** but he might fail to reclaim his throne after being deposed (as you suggest).

You might say that he failed **in claiming the throne** although it's a bit awkward. It's really his claim that fails.

It would read better if you wrote:

The king failed in his ambition to reclaim the throne. (He wouldn't be the king unless he had already been on the throne.)